# Weird system of equations

Tags: recreational-mathematics, puzzle

X : 2 = 7
Y : 2 = 6
X + Y = 15
Find X and Y.

I think maybe this is some unpositional number system. I've tried positional, and it works for basis 21 (if we take X=D, and Y=C), but professor told me that even if that works, it's not solution.

Comment: Stupid question: which operation does ':' denote?

Comment: Regular division. Geometrically solution exists,

Comment: Is it possible that this is a trick question? I think I have seen something like this before which looked like a usual system of equations, but was something like "the first number is the number of circles in the symbol/character"

Comment: I'm not sure. Professor told me only that there is solution, and it can be represented geometrically... nothing else...

Comment: If it's geometric it can be something like $X$ and $Y$ are two triangles and the numbers are their perimeters. So the perimeter of $X$ divided by 2 is 7, and the perimeter of $Y$ divided by 2 is 6. If you combine the two triangles into one shape in a certain way then you get a shape with perimeter 15. This is possible for example the sides of the triangles are $X : (4.5, 4.5, 5)$ and $Y : (4.5, 3.5, 4)$ and you join them along the sides of length 4.5. However this seems pretty farfetched...

Answer (score 1):

Well, $2$ weird solutions related to "geometrical solution":

**Solution 1**:
suppose we have a circle, and $X,Y$ are certain arcs.
 
Let measure of arc is the length of corresponding segment.

Image:

[image]

And so weird answer: 
$$
X\approx 12.4428 (\mbox{radius}\approx 7.63599, \mbox{angle}\approx 1.90458)
$$
$$
Y\approx 11.0351 (\mbox{radius}\approx 7.63599, \mbox{angle}\approx 1.61503)
$$

---

**Solution 2**: in the style of "matches":

$X=7$ matches, 
$Y=8$ matches:

(if there are $\ge 5$, then we group each $5$ matches into "square").

[image]

---

Of course, there can be also solution in "vectors" style.